# MS Access - Continuous Form Select with Dropdown from Another Table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've been using Databasedevelopment.co.uk's excellent example on how to do a continuous form select with a invisible button overlaying a checkbox to assign employees to a specific shift. I'd like to make it so that said continuous form also has a dropdown of the different Paycodes so that when they are selected I can use a combobox to indicate "Regular Pay, Overtime, etc....". I'm running into a wall because with the query as-is from the example, the recordset for the Paycode field is not updateable.

Messing with the primary key for the employee's table fixes the paycode issue but prevents the selection code from working properly.

I'm a bit out of my depth here, what's the easiest way to accomplish this?

```
SELECT CAT.EmployeeID, CAT.FirstName, CAT.LastName, ASGN_TEMP.ShiftNum, ASGN.PayCode, IIf(ASGN_TEMP.[ShiftNum] Is Null,0,-1) AS IsSelected
     FROM tblEmployees AS CAT 

     LEFT JOIN (SELECT ASGN.EmployeeID, ASGN.ShiftNum, ASGN.PayCode FROM tblAssignedEmployees AS ASGN 
          WHERE ASGN.ShiftNum = Forms!frmMainMenu![txtShiftNum])  AS ASGN_TEMP 

     ON CAT.EmployeeID = ASGN_TEMP.EmployeeID;
```

Paycode is a static table with an ID, a Paycode and a description and would only correspond with each record in "tblAssignedEmployee". That is to say, there is no relationship between the employee or the shift with what Paycodes are available, I'd just like a second table for ease of updates.

---EDIT---

Table: Employees

| ID | EmployeeID | Firstname | LastName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | Bob | Jones |
| 2 | 9999 | Mary | Sue |

Table: AssignedEmployees

| ID | EmployeeID | ShiftNum | PayCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | 1 | OT |
| 2 | 9999 | 2 | Regular |
| 3 | 1234 | 2 | OT |

Table: PayCodes

| ID | PayCode | Desc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Regular | Regular Pay |
| 2 | OT | Overtime |

Comment: Not really following that narrative. What does "recordset for the Paycode field is not updateable" mean - why does it need to be? What is `selection code`? Edit question to show sample data as text tables. Consider posting to a forum that allows attaching files and provide db for analysis.

Comment: On further, investigation, the issue is that the recordset is not updateable, and I don't know how to make it so. Even if I get rid of all of the selection code, there's still the same issue. I'll update to map out the tables.

Comment: This is a many-to-many relationship with AssignedEmployees the junction table. Usual approach for data entry is a form/subform arrangement. Are the ID fields designated primary key and the actual values saved into AssignedEmployees? Query references table ASGN but that is not in your schema.

Comment: Ooops, now I see where ASGN is an alias table name.